# Find the basis when integration is in the condition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, schauder-basis

Let $V$ be the set of all polynomial $f(x)$ in $P_2$ s.t. $\int_{0}^3 f(x) dx  =3f(1)  $

If $V$ is a subspace of $P_2$ find a basis of $V$.

Can somebody help me get started? The integral condition kind of scares me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to be scared about with the integral, as long as you can evaluate basic integrals, which I'm sure you can.

Any polynomial in $P_2$ has the form $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2$.  This satisfies your condition if
$$\int_0^3 a+bx+cx^2\,dx=3(a+b+c)\ .$$
If you calculate the integral and simplify this comes down to
$$b=-4c\ .$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{V
  &=\{\,a+bx+cx^2\in P_2\mid b=-4c\,\}\cr
  &=\{\,a-4cx+cx^2\mid a,c\in{\Bbb R}\,\}\cr
  &=\{\,a(1)+c(-4x+x^2)\mid a,c\in{\Bbb R}\,\}\cr
  &=\mathop{\rm span}\{\,1,\,-4x+x^2\,\}\ .\cr}$$
This shows that $\{\,1,\,-4x+x^2\,\}$ is a spanning set for $V$; it is easy to show that it is linearly independent; so it is a basis for $V$.

Comment: $\int_0^3 a+bx+cx^2\,dx=3(a+b+c) $ is pretty. A big thank you for pointing it out @David !

Comment: This is a pretty common technique.  Say there is a matrix example, you want a basis for $\{X\in M_{2,2}\mid \bigl({1\ 2\atop2\ 4}\bigr)X=0\}$, you can start by taking $X=\bigl({a\ b\atop c\ d}\bigr)$ and then work out the algebra.